# Points in Polygon extraction

Tags: python, shapefile, point-in-polygon, las, pdal

I have a shapefile with *MSK-16z2* crs and a las-file which crs can not be recornized by qgis, but attached to the las prj contains also *MSK-16z2*. I need to crop described lasfile by shapefile. I tried to do it with pdal as below:

```
{"type": "filters.crop",
 "polygon": self.shape}
```

I couldn't execute the pipeline, even if add *"a_srs"* parameter (because crs is custom and pdal fails).

Then I tried to find *x,y* coordinate and extract only points which are in the polygon in the following way:

```
 class Crop:
    def __init__(self,
                 outfolder, vls_path, shapefile):
        self.outfolder = outfolder
        self.vls_path = vls_path
        self.csv_name = None
        self.shapefile = shapefile

    def getInfo(self):
        inFile = laspy.read(self.vls_path)
        x_dimension = inFile.x.scaled_array()
        y_dimension = inFile.y.scaled_array()
        return x_dimension, y_dimension

    def getPointsInPoly(self, xs, ys):
        counties = gpd.GeoDataFrame.from_file(self.shapefile)
        df = pd.DataFrame({'lon': xs, 'lat': ys})
        df['coords'] = list(zip(df['lon'], df['lat']))
        df['coords'] = df['coords'].apply(shapely.geometry.Point)
        points = gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='coords', crs=counties.crs)
        pointInPolys = gpd.tools.sjoin(points, counties, op="within", how='left', predicate='contains')
        pointInPolys.to_csv("aoi.csv",
                           header=True,
                           index=False,
                           )

        for q, dn in enumerate(counties.DN):
            pnt_LA = points[pointInPolys.DN == dn]


    def cropCalc(self):
        x, y = self.getInfo()
        self.getPointsInPoly(x, y)

a = Crop(vls_path=laspath,
         outfolder=None,
         shapefile=shapepath)

a.cropCalc()
```

however it didn't work also. The program fails in *getPointsInPoly* function with

> AttributeError: 'GeoDataFrame' object has no attribute 'DN'

error. In which way can I do cropping else via Python?

Comment: Can you post a link to the MSK-16 Zone2 parameters, your point cloud, and the shapefile?